# Which CSS bug is this? (margin-bottom, ie6 + ie7)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

In ie6 and ie7, the `margin-bottom` from the `p` is being applied to both the `p` AND the `div` just below it.

In other words, this code will apply a `margin-bottom` of 20px to both the `p` and the `div` in ie6 and ie7. No problems in any version of FF, Opera, Chrome/Safari or ie8.

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Hello world!</p>
<div style="float: left; display: inline">
    Hello world, part deux.
</div>
```

Of course, removing the float from the div remedies the problem. Which ie/CSS bug is this, if any, and what should I search for to figure out how to fix it?

p.s. I cannot assign a width to the `div`, unfortunately.

Comment: If anyone has a better idea other than adding a `border-bottom` which is blended into the background to the `p`, I'd love to hear it. I thought about maybe throwing in a "hidden" p or div just below it, but don't really like that idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**float: left** will essentially cause your DIV container to be pushed to the top leftmost position possible within the document flow.  In this case, since the previous **P** tag is not floated, the margin bottom is disregarded.  This would have the desired effect, although not very clean code:

```
<p style="float: left; display: inline; margin-bottom: 20px;">Hello world!</p>
<div style="clear: left; float: left; display: inline">
    Hello world, part deux.
</div>
```

It would be ideal, however, to simply remove the float from your element and leave them as they were intended to be (block level elements):

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Hello world!</p>
<div>Hello world, part deux.</div>
```

Perhaps I am missing the intended effect of these two containers in your case.

Comment: I think you're on to it... I want the `p` to stretch all the way across the parent div (with a bg-color, etc.) and have a `margin-bottom` of 20px. The div(s) below it should be floated left.

Comment: do you really need the div to be floated for any given reason? is it not supposed to span the full width?

Comment: Yes, it should be floated left because there will be several divs next to it (to the right of it)... containing form controls. I left them off the code above to keep it simple.

Comment: I really appreciate the input. The only way I've found to make happen what I need to happen is to apply a `border-bottom` to the `p` of the same bg-color as the container. Don't like it, but that's what I did.

Comment: You should try wrapping all of the floated DIVs in a parent DIV **<div style="overflow:hidden"></div>** which will obey the margin-bottom of your P and will also clear your floats of it's contained children.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be encountering the [issue explained here](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html).  Unfortunately, part of the fix is to give the `<div>` a width and make it `display: inline`, things you either can't do or have already done.  Maybe it will help you understand why it's happening though...

Comment: I appreciate the input, but my situation is not the double-margin bug.